# Making SUM in RIGHT JOIN query show both records that have result or not

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

- **Products**: storing product with total qty of each

[image]

- **Orders**: storing orders with their status

[image]

- **Order_items**: storing product and quantity sold in each order

[image]

I need to find a way to list those products with their total quantity and pending quantity (products that customer paid, but haven't been shipped to them yet, in other word, quantity of products in order with status `paid = 1`, `shipped = 0`, `cancelled = 0`). I come up with this SQL command:

```
SELECT 
    products.sku, 
    SUM(order_items.quantity) AS quantity_pending, 
    quantity_total
FROM 
    order_items 
RIGHT JOIN 
    products ON products.sku = order_items.sku 
RIGHT JOIN 
    orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id 
           AND paid = 1 AND shipped = 0 AND cancelled = 0
WHERE  
    products.sku = 'test' 
    OR products.sku = 'test-a' 
    OR products.sku = 'test-b' 
GROUP BY 
    products.sku
```

Expecting the result with be like this:

[image]

But actually I got this:

[image]

Which means mysql only show the result if pending_quantity > 0. Is there a way to achieve what I expected? I don't mind multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a number of problems.  The biggest problem, and the reason that some of your skus are missing from the result set, is that you are right joining finally to the `orders` table.  Since this table only has orders coming from sku `test`, the other skus are being discarded during the join.

The other problem is that you are selecting `quantity_total` from the `products` table, but this column is not an aggregate, even though you are grouping.  The workaround for this, which I have done below, is to use a subquery to compute the pending quantity, and then join this to the `products` table.

```
SELECT p.sku,
       COALESCE(t.quantity_pending, 0) AS quantity_pending,
       p.quantity_total
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT oi.sku, SUM(oi.quantity) AS quantity_pending
    FROM order_items oi
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON oi.order_id = o.id
    WHERE o.paid = 1 AND o.shipped = 0 AND o.cancelled = 0
    GROUP BY oi.sku
) t
    ON p.sku = t.sku
WHERE p.sku IN ('test', 'test-a', 'test-b');
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks you for optimizing my query, but it will sum everything, including completed orders (paid, shipped), instead of only pending orders (paid, not shipped). What I expected will be test = 2, test-a = 0, test-b = 0

Comment: @mee The result set won't change, even after adding the logic you want, because only order #`1` has a product sku, and the sku is `test`.

Comment: What I expected will be `test = 2, test-a = 0, test-b = 0`. The problem I have with original query is, while it's showing correct pending_qty, it doesn't show product with zero pending_qty.

Comment: After trying a few things, I think I have a query which should work for you.  I moved the checks for the order status to the `WHERE` clause of the subquery.  This will eliminate skus which have a zero count, but we can still report 0 for those skus in the outer query using `COALESCE()`.